# How to disable automatic generation of wadl in TomEE?

Tags: rest, cxf, apache-tomee, wadl, tomee-7

http://<>/api?_wadl 
lists all the rest api we have

How to disable automatic generation of these _wadl urls?

Currently all our APIs are publicly exposed, which we do not want for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

question is: do you want to disable the wadl generation or secure your services. Both will prevent to expose the API through the wadl but only last one will not expose anything.

Last one needs a security filter whatever solution you choose (home made, shiro, ...)

If you still want to disable the wadl you can either remove cxf-rt-rs-service-description.jar from tomee lib or just add a `ContainerRequestFilter` as `@Provider` or Filter filtering these calls from within the webapp.

Comment: Unfortunately i can not remove the cxf-rt-rs-service-description jar from lib because I need to expose _wadl for other applications deployed in same tomcat, so only option left now is, have a filter / provider to prevent access to _wadl pattern... let me try that...